# Safe place for an ATL object to release itself

Tags: c++, winapi, atl

Is there a strategy for safely allowing an ATL object to release itself in response to a Windows message or sink event?

In other words, let's say you have an ATL class that's subclassing some windows (using a message map) and/or sinking events from COM objects (using a sink map).  And you'd like the class to release itself given a particular message or event.  For example, you might want to release when a particular subclassed window receives `WM_CLOSE`, or you're sinking `DWebBrowserEvents2` and want to release upon `DISPID_ONQUIT`.

I think the problem is that if you release in the middle of your message or event handler, the ATL framework might still have some processing to do afterward (even if you, say, do something like `bHandled = TRUE`).  And if your object has been released/deleted at that point, then bad things will ensue.

Does anyone know of an approach to solve this?  Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do next implementation

```
class MySubClass : public CWindowImplBaseT<>
{
    ULONG dwRefCount = 1;

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(MySubClass)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CHAR, OnChar)
    END_MSG_MAP()

    LRESULT OnChar(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        bHandled = FALSE;

        // for instance unsublass when ESC pressed
        // but possible do this on any event
        if (uMsg == WM_CHAR && wParam == VK_ESCAPE)
        {
            UnsubclassWindow(FALSE);
        }

        return 0;   
    }

    virtual void OnFinalMessage(_In_ HWND hWnd)
    {
        __super::OnFinalMessage(hWnd);
        Release();
    }

    ~MySubClass()
    {
        DbgPrint("%s<%p>\n", __FUNCTION__, this);
    }

public:

    BOOL SubclassWindow(_In_ HWND hWnd)
    {
        if (__super::SubclassWindow(hWnd))
        {
            AddRef();
            return TRUE;
        }

        return FALSE;
    }

    HWND UnsubclassWindow(_In_ BOOL bForce /*= FALSE*/)
    {
        if (HWND hwnd = __super::UnsubclassWindow(bForce))
        {
            // mark window as destroyed
            m_dwState |= WINSTATE_DESTROYED;
            m_hWnd = hwnd;
            return hwnd;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    void AddRef()
    {
        dwRefCount++;
    }

    void Release()
    {
        if (!--dwRefCount)
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }
};

void DoSubclass(HWND hwnd)
{
    if (MySubClass* pObj = new MySubClass)
    {
        pObj->SubclassWindow(hwnd);

        pObj->Release();
    }
}
```

so key points - have reference count on object ( `ULONG dwRefCount`  - here i assume that object will be accessed only from single UI thread, otherwise need use atomic/interlocked operations). delete object inside `Release()` when `dwRefCount` became 0. when we subclass window - add additional reference, and in UnsubclassWindow - set `WINSTATE_DESTROYED` bit in state ( `m_dwState |= WINSTATE_DESTROYED` ) - as result `OnFinalMessage` will be called after last message and here we already call `Release`. or if we not direct unsubclass until window will be destroyed - atl implementation anyway finally call `OnFinalMessage` where we release self.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for CWindowImpl::OnFinalMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/reference/cwindowimpl-class?view=msvc-160#onfinalmessage):

> The default implementation of `OnFinalMessage` does nothing, but you can override this function to handle cleanup before destroying a window. If you want to automatically delete your object upon the window destruction, you can call `delete this;` in this function.

So that looks like the place to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I don't think that solves the problem.  Because I'm mainly concerned about subclassed windows, not my own, and sink events.  `OnFinalMessage` would just get triggered if my own window was being destroyed.

Comment: @user15025873 - after you success call `UnsubclassWindow` you need *mark self window as destroyed* by do `m_dwState |= WINSTATE_DESTROYED;`, as result `OnFinalMessage` will be called on your class object